# Can't use self.request in Serializer: Any way to check logged-in user in Serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm facing the inevitable situation that I have to check user's logged in in Serializer. It returns whether logged-in user have **liked the post or not**

Here is PostDetailView.

```
class PostDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Outfit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

This is its serializer

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    like_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            ...
            'like_count',
            'liked',
            ...
        )

    def get_liked(self, obj):
        content_type = obj.get_content_type
        object_id = obj.id
        ### Right Here! I can't get self.request.user;
        my_like = Like.objects.filter_by_instance(obj).filter(user=self.request.user)

        if my_like == 0:
            return False
        return True

    # this is just an example
    def get_like_count(self, obj):
        content_type = obj.get_content_type
        object_id = obj.id
        like_count = Like.objects.filter_by_instance(obj).count()
        return like_count
```

Since Serializer doesn't have `request` attribute, we can't import it. How can I return whether the post is liked or not?

More info: I have explicit `Like` model to store user's likes

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
```

Maybe I can use ModelManager to solve this problem. But ModelManager doesn't have `request` either! Frustrating... :(

Comment: You can access `request` from serializer like, `self.context['request']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
def get_liked(self, obj):
    content_type = obj.get_content_type
    object_id = obj.id
    user = self.context['request'].user
    my_like = Like.objects.filter_by_instance(obj).filter(user=user)

    if my_like.count() == 0:
        return False
    return True
```

Serializer, now has the `request` object in its context dictionary.

Comment: PERFECT! It worked! I can accept the question in 8 minutes. Could you explain more about 'context'?

Comment: Each serializer object has a context dictionary, which holds the request object by default when initialised. You can pass literally anything from view into serializer context like, `YourSerializer(data=data, context={'name':'name'})` and `name` can be accessed from the serializer object.